# c# Blazor Generic Page with child components

Tags: c#, generics, razor, types, blazor

I'm making a CRUD application, and have a generic component form that uses reflection to build itself, however i'm stuck on how to make the page generic without it becoming a maintenance nightmare.

The page code;

```
@page "/RecordDetails/{type}/{id}/{returnPath}"
@page "/NewRecord/{type}/{returnPath}"
@inject NavigationManager nm;

@if (type == "Type1")
{
    <InputGenericForm ItemID="@id" ItemType="Type1" FormCancelled="ReturnToSender" FormDeleted="ReturnToSender" FormSaved="ReturnToSender" />
}

@if (type == "Type2")
{
    <InputGenericForm ItemID="@id" ItemType="Type2" FormCancelled="ReturnToSender" FormDeleted="ReturnToSender" FormSaved="ReturnToSender" />
}

etc....


@code {

    [Parameter] public string type { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string id { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string returnPath { get; set; }

    private bool isCreate { get { if (id == null) { return true; } return false; } }

    private void ReturnToSender()
    {
        nm.NavigateTo(returnPath);
    }

}
```

The "InputGenericForm" component header block of code is as follows;

```
@typeparam ItemType
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
@inject IDataService<ItemType> dataService
@inject IJSRuntime js;
```

While this ***technically*** works, it's getting to be quite cumbersome to maintain, and i'm looking to expand this page so there's other generic components on the page as well, which would require another if block, or switch statement.

I've tried using a function to get this as follows;

```
<InputGenericForm ItemID="@id" ItemType="@Type.GetType(type)" FormCancelled="ReturnToSender" FormDeleted="ReturnToSender" FormSaved="ReturnToSender" />
```

and

```
<InputGenericForm ItemID="@id" ItemType="typeof(Type.GetType(type))" FormCancelled="ReturnToSender" FormDeleted="ReturnToSender" FormSaved="ReturnToSender" />
```

But I get the error message below;

Error   CS0426  The type name 'GetType' does not exist in the type 'Type'

Is there a way I can specify the type into a generic component in this way, or am I stuck with numerous if blocks for this?

TIA

Comment: You could try having a parameter that uses `ItemType` so then you don't need to pass the type directly, just pass the property

Comment: I did try that as well, but then i get the issue raised in this question; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61223459/using-generic-types-with-inheritance-in-blazor-component